# Not setting AJAX properly for IE 7,8 & 9

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer

I am having problems understanding piece of Jquery code. I am trying to enable application (Backbone) to work in IE 7, 8 & 9. Problem is with Jquery (Version 1.10.2) Ajax preparation:

```
  function createStandardXHR() {

    debugger;
    try {
        return new window.XMLHttpRequest();
    } catch( e ) {}
}

function createActiveXHR() {
    try {
        return new window.ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    } catch( e ) {}
}

// Create the request object
// (This is still attached to ajaxSettings for backward compatibility)
jQuery.ajaxSettings.xhr = window.ActiveXObject ?
    /* Microsoft failed to properly
     * implement the XMLHttpRequest in IE7 (can't request local files),
     * so we use the ActiveXObject when it is available
     * Additionally XMLHttpRequest can be disabled in IE7/IE8 so
     * we need a fallback.
     */
    function() {
        return !this.isLocal && createStandardXHR() || createActiveXHR();
    } :
    // For all other browsers, use the standard XMLHttpRequest object
    createStandardXHR;

// Determine support properties
xhrSupported = jQuery.ajaxSettings.xhr();
jQuery.support.cors = !!xhrSupported && ( "withCredentials" in xhrSupported );
xhrSupported = jQuery.support.ajax = !!xhrSupported;
```

To be more precise:

```
jQuery.support.cors = !!xhrSupported && ( "withCredentials" in xhrSupported );
```

In IE 7,8 & 9 gives False and prevents my application to continue further. I can make my own detection for specific IE version, but Jquery should do this automatically... or I am failing something?

Comment: It's returning false for IE 7, 8, and 9 because those browsers don't support CORS. What is your question exactly?

Comment: IE 7 doesn't even run on any supported OS. Why in the world would you be writing new code to target a browser literally nobody should be running?

Comment: Jason. My question is should I alter jquery so it think those browsers support CORS. Aparently Ajax is not formed for those browsers. If I set it to true, then it works. I am wondering is there something else I could do? Joel you are correct, I will not pursue IE6... no reason to do that.